# How to write my component for joomla with another language?

Tags: joomla

I writed a component for joomla
I want use more than once language.Ex english & Itatly
But i don't know how to do it.
Use component joomfish but only effect with component exsist on this joomla version,
not effect with my component ?
How to config my component ?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need Jomfish, Joomla has this capability inside.

You need to use JText and language files.

Step 1: Instead of `echo 'Hello'` use `echo JText::_('COM_EXAMPLE_HELLO')`

Step 2: Create a file language/en-GB/en-GB.com_example.ini

Step 3: In the ini file, enter `COM_EXAMPLE_HELLO=Hello`

Step 4: In the installer XML, don't forget the language ini file: http://docs.joomla.org/Components:xml_installfile

Comment: thanks for answer, a question:
JText::_('abc');
in *.ini
abc=123;
ABC=456;
when change language will get 456 ? why not 123 ?

Comment: I guess it's a question to Joomla devs - http://groups.google.com/group/joomla-dev-cms

Comment: Language string IDs are case insensitive (they are uppercased before checked). Why would you want to use the same key with different casing anyway?

Answer (score 1):

you add your selected language in main xml file and install xml file to add your language and one more simple way to create components

http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/

also you u create about your requirement than you add easily multiple language ..